# Is there a plugin for Vim that would help me debugging like Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, debugging, vim, ssh

The reason why I'm asking this, is because I'm coding in C++, in putty/ssh and I like the fact that I can code from pretty much everywhere without having to install anything.

So I'd like to have something that could help me debugging (viewing LIVE value of a variable, breakpoints, etc)

If you think that there's no such thing in this world, is there any good technique I could use to debug in command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used gdb for command line debugging in the past with success:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

A decent tutorial can be found at:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks I had seen it already, but it seems the best solution so far... Also seems a little tricky of use.. But anyway... This is command line, I was kind of expecting this.

Comment: @Pacane: If you're looking for something a little shinier, you could try [CGDB](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/). It uses curses, so it can display a little more - in particular, it has a source view - but is still usable over SSH in a terminal. If you have an X display, you could try [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), a graphical front-end for GDB.

Answer (score 3):

[vimgdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clewn/files/vimGdb/) will give what you want. I've used it for about one year. The most interesting feature is:

- Hightlight current line
- List item
- Can show disassembly code
- Step into, Step over
- inspect variables, memory address
- Run all the underlying gdb command is possible
- And, of course, set breakpoint, conditional breakpoint etc.

Highly customizable by vim key mapping and scripts.

Actually I use checkinstall to make an rpm for it, and installed it everywhere when I need to debug on the box.

I think it have the most important features I want from a visual debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `gdb` ? That's pretty much **the** command line debugger, but it's no vim plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have a script to do that: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1954

In my humble opinion, Vim is not designed to do such things and it is a bad idea to do so.

Comment: I've never used the script. What about Vim's design makes it a bad idea to do things like that?